# Seamlessly updating a large collection of Redis keys and values

Tags: redis

I have a large collection of Redis key/value pairs in some namespace (i.e. the key has some prefix). The source for this collection is updated periodically; it mostly stays the same, but some keys are added, others are removed, and some have updated values.

What is an efficient way to update the collection in Redis without any downtime to the application using the collection? It is not required that the update be atomic.

Comment: What's the problem with just performing the data sync in the background?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev By "data sync", it sounds like you're implying knowledge of the delta between the old and new versions of the collection. I added this approach as an answer. It requires traversing the entirety of the old and new collections. Since the old collection is irrelevant after the update, I was wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: Alternatively, you can upload your new collection to a new prefix ("mycollection:v0034:*"). When upload is done, switch application to use the new prefix and remove the now-obsolete keys from the old prefix

Comment: You can do data sync without calculating the delta: just take your new collection and push the values with a TTL roughly equal to `time between syncs + duration of data sync`. This will take care of new and updated keys. And deleted keys will remove themselves when they expire (shortly after the next sync).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Using TTL is clever and sounds convenient, but might be difficult to make robust if something went wrong. It's like initiating the self destruct sequence on your old spaceship and then proceeding to build up the improved model. It makes for a clean transition - if all goes as planned. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it has its drawbacks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Calculate a sync delta (add, removes, updates) between the existing Redis collection and the updated source collection.
2. Update the Redis collection using the sync delta.

Depending on how frequent the source updates are, you may want to keep the local copy of the existing Redis collection in memory to speed up step 1 and take load off the Redis server.